# Why is my Python conditional within function not working?

Tags: python

```
def blood_pressure(systolic, diastolic):

    mean_pressure = (systolic + (2 * diastolic)) / 3

    risk = float(1.0)

    risk_return = round((risk * mean_pressure), 2)

    if diastolic < 80:
        if systolic < 120:
            return(risk_return)
        else:
            risk += 0.1
            return(risk_return) 
    return

print(blood_pressure(121,75))
```

when I run this code, it outputs the number as if it went though the first conditional `if systolic < 120`, instead of the `else` conditional. I need it to add the `0.1` to the original risk but its not going through properly. Sorry this is really basic I am just getting into coding. What is going wrong?

Comment: in what case you want to add 0.1 ?

Comment: What's the purpose of incrementing the local variable `risk` if it goes out of scope immediately?

Comment: `float(1.0)` seems redundant

Comment: `risk += 0.1` doesn't affect `risk_return`, why would you expect `risk_return` to be different when you don't change it?

Comment: How do you know it goes through the if statement? your return value doesnt change. changing the value of `risk` does not change the value of `risk_return`

Comment: Also, what output are you getting vs what do you expect? In other words, why do you think it should behave other than as coded?

Comment: I want to add 0.1 if diastolic < 80 and systolic >= 120. So any systolic value that is >= 120 should fall under the else statement.

Comment: Also, don't forget that you're returning None half the time

Comment: Run this in a debugger to trace your code

Comment: So the question is, you have written `risk += 0.1` and then `return(risk_return)`, and you are seeing the same behaviour as in the other branch of the `if` condition, where you only have `return(risk_return)`. Yes? So, my question for you is: why do you expect that writing `risk += 0.1` first should change the effect of `return(risk_return)`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you calculate `risk_return` too early:

```py
def blood_pressure(systolic, diastolic):
    mean_pressure = (systolic + (2 * diastolic)) / 3
    risk = 1.0

    if diastolic < 80 and systolic >= 120:
        risk += 0.1

    return round((risk * mean_pressure), 2)


print(blood_pressure(121,75))
```

Comment: `if diastolic < 80 and systolic >= 120:` instead of nesting two if-statements also works